# Reactjs Server Side Rendering FOUC issue

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

After implementing Server Side Rendering in my reactjs app, whenever my page is loaded it does not apply styles to the page until the js is loaded from the server. This creates an FOUC issue. I tried using **extract-text-webpack-plugin** but it still does not work even though my styles are exported into a different CSS file and I've included exported CSS file in my html file. Below is my webpack configuration.

```
module.exports = {
  context: path.join(__dirname, "src"),
  devtool: "inline-source-map",
  entry: ['webpack-hot-middleware/client', './app/js/index.js'
  ],
  module: {
  loaders: [
  {
    test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
    loader: "file-loader"
  },
  {
    test: /\.css$/,
    loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style-loader", "css-loader")
  },
  { test: /\.scss$/,
    loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('css!sass')
  }
 ]
},
output: {
  path: path.join(__dirname, "build"),
  filename: "index.min.js",
  publicPath: '/'
},

 plugins: [
  new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
  new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
  new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),

  new ExtractTextPlugin("./src/app/style.css",{
   allChunks:false
 })
 ]
 };
```

Hope anyone has found out the solution with an explanation.

Comment: What's your html template look like? If you're properly server side rendering, it might make sense to remove the js client side bundle from the page temporarily and confirm that the FOUC is gone.

Comment: I removed js client side bundle and still the css is applied.

Comment: Is the fouc gone?

Comment: @DrewSchuster Yes. When server was printing html string it wasn't including the class attribute and hence until client side js takes over classes were not getting applied.

Comment: Any updates for this?

Comment: @ShubhamKushwah The actual issue was that I was using `class` attribute and not the `className` to apply CSS styling, is why until the client-side js was taking over, classes were not getting applied.